# No response from Google analytics server after sending an HTTP request for the _utm.gif file

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I registered account at https://www.google.com/analytics/, loaded the lib, deployed sample project from zip and update the id to tracker in format `UA-11111-1` and setup debug mode.

In logcat I can't find the response `200 OK`. Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your id cannot be recognized. If you are using xml resource to store your id, use "-" instead of "-" e.g. UA-11111--1

Comment: thanks for the answer but I am not using xml file to store the ID. The ID is located in the code.

Comment: I got the same problem yesterday which I could not understand why. This morning I used another one and it worked. Try restart Eclipse or clean your workspace. You can also check the logcat if it contains the id you expected in that long string from GoogleAnalyticsTracker. Besides you might need to wait 24 hours for GA website to be ready for use if you have just resisted.

Comment: Hi, I am waiting for 3 days now and I think I am going crazy. As I understand after the dispatching the logcat suppose to display a response for a successful HTTP request called ("200 OK") is it true?

Comment: Yes that's true. It would say HTTP Response Code:200

Comment: which jar file do you use libGoogleAnalytics.jar or libGoogleAnalyticsV2.jar? and please can you tell how you implement it. I am trying to use the sample they put with the jar file.

Comment: I'm using version 1.5(?) rather than v2, and you can check Google analytics android developer page , it contains a quite straightforward event demo you can use. Unfortunately, I cannot open that page currently.

Comment: I am using the demo but it is not working. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I would say Flurry is a better choice for Android. You can have a try.

Comment: crazy but suddenly It started to work I didn't change anything. Thanks!!

Comment: The sample that comes with GoogleAnalytics download is not compatible with libGoogleAnalyticsV2.jar